# Riemann Roch Theorem for Rank $2$ Bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-curves

I am aware that there is Riemann Roch for vector bundles in general, but I am trying to show this for the special case of rank two vector bundles $V$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$. Specifically, how does one show

$h^0(V)=\deg(V)+2+h^1(V)$?

Comment: All vector bundles on $\mathbb P^1$ splits into direct sum of line bundles. So I guess you can use the RR for line bundles? Just assume $V = O(k_1) \oplus O(k_2)$.

Comment: I thought that RR for vector bundles is part of the proof that all vector bundles split into a direct sum of line bundles. In that case this would be circular

Comment: @TejasRao I don't think so. I'm pretty sure the proof of the [Birkhoff-Grothendieck Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff%E2%80%93Grothendieck_theorem) that I know just uses properties of cohomology groups and the long exact sequence. And Birkhoff proved this result just in terms of matrices.

Comment: Is there a more elementary way to show this?